# Is there a way to find out an unexpected mongodb error from the ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to find out an unexpected error occurred in mongoDB and I only have these files

I have opened the binary files but I have not found relevant information

http://imgfz.com/i/5L0GBqe.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "find an unexpected error "?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getLog](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getLog/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.getLog):

As explained into docs:

With this you get the available log filters for passing to `getLog`

```bash
db.adminCommand( { getLog: "*" } )
```

And then you can use:

```bash
db.adminCommand( { getLog : "global" } )
```

Or also you can do `show logs` to display all logs and then `show logs <name>`